# Segfault when Associated Type conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I have a problem with Swift compiler segfaulting when trying to compile the code below.

I've already posted a bug report on this, but wonder if:
1) I'm doing anything inherently wrong
2) there is a 'workaround' I could use to achieve a similar result. I suppose not, but I'd appreciate any ideas you might have

```
class Foo<T, U: AnyObject> {

}

protocol Bar {
  typealias T: AnyObject // <- that appears to be the problem
  func foo() -> Foo<Self, T>
}

extension String: Bar {
  func foo() -> Foo<String, NSString> {
    return Foo<String, NSString>()
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't found a solution, but I've done some further testing. It seems that the compiler segfaults if the associated type comes from Foundation or UIKit. It compiles with associated type being our own Swift or Objective-C class. It also compiles if it is a class from SceneKit or CoreData. You might want to check this yourself and update your bug report. If your associated type will always be a Cocoa class, a workaround might be to use 'typealias T: NSObject'.

Comment: @IvicaM. great insight! Thanks for the workaround. So far it appears to do the trick! Is there any key difference between `T: NSObject` and `T: AnyObject`? `AnyObject` allows plain swift classes while `NSObject` does not, right? By the way, feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it :)